# Using Enums to return a different action for each different object

Tags: java, oop, object, enums

I have a list of Player Objects that contain details such as below

```
Player{FirstName='Marco', LastName='Reus', Team='Dortmund', Country='Germany', Fitness='Unfit', RecoveryTime='Slow'}
```

This program is essentially designed to take the players fitness and recovery time into account and return a set of action plans to help them get fit.

I've utilised enums and given each enum an integer value `aValue`.

```
public enum LevelOfFitness {
    /**
     * Enum that represent the different level of Fitness of each player
     */

    CAREER_IN_DOUBT(8), INDEFINITELY_INJURED(7), INJURED(6), UNFIT(5), CLOSE_TO_FITNESS(4), 
NEAR_MATCH_FIT(3),
    MATCH_FIT(2), DATA_DEFICIENT(1), NOT_EVALUATED(0);

    private int value;

    LevelOfFitness (int aValue) {
        this.value = aValue;
    }

    public int getValue () {
        return value;
    }


}
```

I have also got a set of enum action plans:

```
public enum ActionPlans{


    GRADUAL_REHABILITATION, SURGERY, INTENSE_GYM_AND_THERAPY, NO_ACTION_NEEDED,REST_AND_REHABILITATION 

}
```

I'm trying to for example for Marco in the example, if the player is 5 in LevelofFitness which is unfit and recovery time is slow, return Gradual rehabilitation as a action plan.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an extra method `LevelOfFitness.from(String)`  and another `getActionPlan` for given player.

```java
public LevelOfFitness from(String value){  
  // do some input checks

  LevelOfFitness found = null;
  for(LevelOfFitness level : LevelOfFitness.values()){
      if(level.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
         return level;
      }
  }

   throw new IllegalStateException("Not able to find fitness level for " + value);
}


 public ActionPlans getActionPlan(Player player){

        String fitness = player.getFitness();
        LevelOfFitness levelOfFitness = LevelOfFitness.from(fitness);

        ActionPlans actionPlan = null;
        if(fitnessLevelOfFitness.getValue() == 5){
            actionPlan = GRADUAL_REHABILITATION;
        }

        .....

        return actionPlan;
    }
```

You could even put such method inside Player class itself, in this case you could encapsulate further the logic without passing the player reference.

Comment: thanks, for the extra method of LevelOfFitness.from(String) what would that look like,  is that just returning the level of fitness of each object so it can be called in the get action plan method.

Comment: @user14087442 Updated with more details. You need by given string to retrieve the LevelOfFitness.
Example: Unfit -> will get UNFIT(5) enum by comparing names enum and later you could easily its value 5

Comment: where is `from`  in public LevelOfFitness from(String value) referring to?

Comment: @user14087442 Please have a look into the code, inside  `getActionPlan` there is a call `LevelOfFitness levelOfFitness = LevelOfFitness.from(fitness);`